# LockScreen for windows phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone

Hi I am developing a lockscreen app where I am using listbox of images.After selecting a image when i am clicking a button to set lockscreen,It should updated.But it bot updating .Here is my code

```
private async void ApplicationBarIconButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MediaLibrary mediaLibrary = new MediaLibrary();
        //ImageSource im = image1.Source;
        BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
        bitmap.SetSource(mediaLibrary.Pictures[imageList.SelectedIndex].GetImage());

        String tempJPEG = "MyWallpaper1.jpg";

        using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            if (myIsolatedStorage.FileExists(tempJPEG))
            {
                myIsolatedStorage.DeleteFile(tempJPEG);
            }

            IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = myIsolatedStorage.CreateFile(tempJPEG);

            StreamResourceInfo sri = null;
            Uri uri = new Uri(tempJPEG, UriKind.Relative);
            sri = Application.GetResourceStream(uri);

            WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(bitmap);

            Extensions.SaveJpeg(wb, fileStream, wb.PixelWidth, wb.PixelHeight, 0, 90);

            fileStream.Close();
        }

        LockScreenChange(tempJPEG);

    }

    private async void LockScreenChange(string filePathOfTheImage)
    {
        if (!LockScreenManager.IsProvidedByCurrentApplication)
        {
            await LockScreenManager.RequestAccessAsync();
        }

        if (LockScreenManager.IsProvidedByCurrentApplication)
        {
            var schema = "ms-appdata:///Local/";
            var uri = new Uri(schema + filePathOfTheImage, UriKind.Absolute);

            LockScreen.SetImageUri(uri);
            var currentImage = LockScreen.GetImageUri();
            MessageBox.Show("Success", "LockScreen changed", MessageBoxButton.OK);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Background cant be changed. Please check your permissions to this application.");
        }
    }
```

Actually when first time the app is launched and when I am clicking set button,the current selected image is set as lockscreen,after that when i am selecting another image,it is showing lockscreen changed ,success.No error and no exception.I dont know where is the problem.
Please help........

Comment: A cast exception means you're using the wrong types. Look at the return type of each method you're using and make sure it matches what the method parameters require.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It got solved by changing temporary file name to original file name i.e. string tempJpeg